# How I can test a particular method in my Service class using Mock C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Please help me with my issue. I have a Service class which is given below:

```
public class RateService:IRatesService
{
    ...
    public RatesDTO GetById(int Id)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Rates, RatesDTO>(this.db.Rates.GetAll().Where(m => m.RateId == Id).First());
    }
}
```

An interface IRatesServicelooks like that sample of code:

```
public interface IRatesService
{
    .....
    RatesDTO GetById(int Id);
    ....
}
```

And now I try to test public RatesDTO GetById(int Id) method. My code is given below:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Mock<IRatesService> mock = new Mock<IRatesService>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<RatesDTO>(total=>total);

        Assert.IsNotNull(mock.Object.GetById(1));
    }
}
```

But  when I run test I get an error like this:

> Test Name:    TestMethod1 Test
>   FullName: Provider.Tests.Services.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
>
> Result Message:
>
> Test method Provider.Tests.Services.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw
>   exception:  System.ArgumentException: Невозможно преобразовать объект
>   типа "System.Int32" к типу "Provider.BLL.DTO.RatesDTO".

What is the best practice to test the Service classes and methods?

Comment: If you are trying to test RateService you should test the concrete class and you shouldn't mock it. Mocks exists for cases when you want to test class in isolation so you mock the objects the class dependent on.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to test your mock. That doesn't make any sense.

**You should strive to test your actual code.**
In your case, you might want to make sure that your GetById returns RatesDTO with the right id value.

You could use Mock framework, to facilitate your testing.
e.g. if you are trying to perform a unit-test and you are using a DB layer you might want to mock the database layer GetAll function and return several objects and then run a test to check that you actually return the right object (same id).

Answer (score 0):

Your `RateService` is the system under test. When creating mocks for your unit tests the norm is to mock the dependencies of your system under test.

So given your current service lets say it has a dependency on a data store.

```
public class RateService : IRatesService {
    private readonly IDbContext db;
    public RateService(IDbContext dbContext) {
        this.db = dbContext;
    }
    //...
    public RatesDTO GetById(int Id) {
        return Mapper.Map<Rates, RatesDTO>(this.db.Rates.GetAll().Where(m => m.RateId == Id).First());
    }
    //...
}
```

`IDbContext` would be the dependency of the system under test.

You would mock that up when testing `RateService`

```
[TestClass]
public class RateServiceUnitTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Given_ValidId_GetById_Should_Return_Dto() {
        //Arrange
        var validId = 1;
        var fakes = new List<Rates>() {
            new Rates { RateId = validId }
        };
        var mock = new Mock<IDbContext>();
        //Assuming IDbContext.Rates.GetAll() returns an IEnumerable<Rates>
        mock.Setup(m => m.Rates.GetAll()).Returns(fakes);
        var sut = new RateService(mock.Object);
        //Act
        var result = sut.GetById(validId);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

Noticed that you are also using a mapper. You should make sure that is configured for the test as well otherwise the test will fail. When using static calls in your classes they can cause issues when you try to isolate your system for testing. Try adding the mapper as a dependency as well.